# Unable to Add onClick / Event Listener to a ListItem in MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently unable to add a simple event listener to a `ListItem` in MaterialUI, and it's not being heard. Any ideas why this may be?

#### Steps to Reproduce

Using the latest core release (4.9.10), build a simple list using the .map() approach:

```
<List dense={true}>
 {
   types.map(({ icon, primary, secondary }) => (
     <ListItem key={primary} onClick={() => console.log(primary)}>
       <ListItemIcon>
         { icon }
       </ListItemIcon>
       <ListItemText
         primary={primary}
         secondary={secondary}
       />
   </ListItem>
   ))
 }
 </List>
```

#### Environment

- Material-UI   v4.9.10
- React v16.12.0

Comment: Does the parent have pointerEvents "none" like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55405511/1641941)?

Comment: I test here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-oi3bu, there is no problem. Whould share your `types` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code runs for me:

```
import React from 'react';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';


export default function DemoList() {
  const types=[{
    icon: 'icon',
    primary:'primaryText',
    secondary:'secondaryText'
  }]

  return (
    <List dense={true}>
 {
   types.map(({ icon, primary, secondary }) => (
     <ListItem key={primary} onClick={() => {console.log(primary)}}>
       <ListItemIcon>
         { icon }
       </ListItemIcon>
       <ListItemText
         primary={primary}
         secondary={secondary}
       />
   </ListItem>
   ))
 }
 </List>
  );
}
```